# Zip File - is it possible to paginate through the file data?

Tags: pagination, zip, deflate

Say I have a really large zip file (80GB) containing one massive CSV file (> 200GB). 
Is it possible to fetch a subsection of the 80GB file data, modify the central directory, and extract just that bit of data?

Pictorial representation:

[image]

Background on my problem:

I have a cyclic process that does a summing on a certain column of a large zipped CSV file stashed in the cloud.

What I do today is I stream the file to my disk, extract it and then stream the file line by line. This makes is a very disk bound operation. Disk IS the bottle neck for sure.

Sure, I can leverage other cloud services to get what I need faster but that is not free.

I'm curious if I can see speed gains by just taking 1GB sub sections of zip until there's nothing left to read.

What I know:

- The Zip file is stored using the [deflate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) compression algorithm (always)
- In the [API I use](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html) to get the file from the cloud, I can specify a byte range to filter to. This means I can seek through the bytes of a file without hitting disk!
- According the [zip file specs](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) there are three major parts to a zip file in order:

1: A header describing the file and it's attributes

2: The raw file data in deflated format

3: The central directory listing out what files start and stop and what bytes

What I don't know:

- How the deflate algorithm works exactly. Does it jumble the file up or does it just compress things in order of the original file? If it does jumble, this approach may not be possible.
- Had anyone built a tool like this already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always decompress starting *from the beginning*, going as far as you like, keeping only the last, say, 1 GB, once you get to where you want. You cannot just start decompressing somewhere in the middle. At least not with a normal .zip file that has not been very specially prepared somehow for random access.

The central directory has nothing to do with random access of a single entry. All it can do is tell you where an entry starts and how long it is (both compressed and uncompressed).

I would recommend that you reprocess the .zip file into a .zip file with many (~200) entries, each on the order of 1 GB uncompressed. The resulting .zip file will be very close to the same size, but you can then use the central directory to pick one of the 200 entries, randomly access it, and decompress just that one.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I dug through the deflate code and you are sadly correct. You can't just take the middle and decompress it. The deflate algorithm builds trees of the symbols. You can't extract a sub section of the tree and expect any program to know what to do with it. Also, there isn't much I can do about controlling how the file is deflated or breaking the large file up the into N files as the files generation is not in my control. I have reached a dead end it seems :(